# differing output from exactly the same binary

Tags: c, arrays

I am busy working through some coding exercises on Project Euler. I have what I think is a strange situation.

When I compile the code below, I get varying output. I can find not reason for this. I suspect I have some error in my code, but even when I run it through GDB, I can't seem to track down the bug.

The varying output is below the code. I am running on Linux Mint (Cinnamon), in VirtualBox 6.1, on a Windows 10 host. All installations are x64. All the necessary header files are included above the #define's (but not shown here).

As far as I can tell the problem code has to be in the function "FindSmallestSuffix".

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10
#define MAX_LOOP 10

int FindPivot(int[], int);

int FindSmallestSuffix(int[], int, int);


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arr[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_LOOP; i++)
    {
        int pivot = FindPivot(arr,ARRAY_SIZE);
        if (pivot != -1)
        {
            int smallestIdx = FindSmallestSuffix(arr,pivot,ARRAY_SIZE);
            printf("Pivot = %d;",pivot);
            printf("Idx smallest = %d;",smallestIdx);
            printf("Interation = %d\n",i);
        }
        else
            printf("Number Optimised!\n");
    }

    //PrintArray(arr, ARRAY_SIZE);

    printf("\n");
}

int FindPivot(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (i != 0 && arr[i-1] < arr[i])
            return i-1;
    return -1;
}

int FindSmallestSuffix(int arr[], int pivot, int size)
{
    int smallest = 10;  
    int marker = 0;
    for (int i = size; i > pivot; i--)
        if (arr[i] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = arr[i];
            marker = i;
        }
    return marker;
}
```

Here is the varying output ("Idx smallest" is 10 in one case and 9 in another):

```
xxx@xxx-VirtualBox:~/dev/project_euler$ ./a.out
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 10;Interation = 1
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 10;Interation = 2
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 10;Interation = 3
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 10;Interation = 4
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 10;Interation = 5
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 10;Interation = 6
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 10;Interation = 7
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 10;Interation = 8
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 10;Interation = 9
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 10;Interation = 10

xxx@xxx-VirtualBox:~/dev/project_euler$ ./a.out
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 9;Interation = 1
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 9;Interation = 2
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 9;Interation = 3
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 9;Interation = 4
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 9;Interation = 5
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 9;Interation = 6
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 9;Interation = 7
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 9;Interation = 8
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 9;Interation = 9
Pivot = 8;Idx smallest = 9;Interation = 10
```

Comment: in `FindSmallestPivot` you have `for (int i = size; i > pivot; i--) { if (arr[i] < smallest) .... ` so you access `arr[size]` what is out of bounds. So you're experiencing Undefined Behaviour

Comment: Hello Ingo, thanks very much. Missed that, sometimes when I stare at a problem for too long even the obvious is hidden, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is line 47 in `FindSmallestSuffix`. You're off by one.

You can find the problem with clang's memory sanitizer:

```
$ clang -fsanitize=address -Wall -g a.c -o a && ./a

==579==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fffff2bc5e8 at pc 0x000000512525 bp 0x7fffff2bc540 sp 0x7fffff2bc538
READ of size 4 at 0x7fffff2bc5e8 thread T0
    #0 0x512524 in FindSmallestSuffix /mnt/c/Users/paul/Desktop/a.c:47:13
    #1 0x51224b in main /mnt/c/Users/paul/Desktop/a.c:20:31
    #2 0x7f98d6d7bb96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #3 0x419d19 in _start (/mnt/c/Users/paul/Desktop/a+0x419d19)

Address 0x7fffff2bc5e8 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 72 in frame
    #0 0x5120ef in main /mnt/c/Users/paul/Desktop/a.c:12

  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 72) 'arr' (line 13) <== Memory access at offset 72 overflows this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow /mnt/c/Users/paul/Desktop/a.c:47:13 in FindSmallestSuffix
```